# Figure-specific vs general properties in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I am trying to understand how methods and attributes are organized in matplotlib. For example, say I have a figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_fig = plt.imshow(image)
```

I have noticed that some figure properties are set via module methods, e.g.:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

while others are set for the figure itself using object methods:

```
my_fig.set_cmap('hot')
```

Can figure properties be specified in either way?

How can I turn `off` the `axis` by calling methods on my object `my_fig`?

Answer (score 2):

The `plt` methods are part of the [pyplot API](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), which is intended to provide Matlab-like convenience for interactive use (and certainly appears to be very influenced by Matlab).  But it's just one small facet of the whole [matplotlib API](http://matplotlib.org/api/index.html) (which is much more OOP).  In practice I seem to end up mixing them both myself in SW; it's largely a matter of taste whether you go through the pyplot API or access the objects.  pyplot is certainly very convenient although as you want to do more complex/exotic things you'll find what you can do with pyplot alone limited and you'll need to get to know at least the full API's Axes, Figure, Legend and Path objects better.

Answer (score 1):

[Pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) is a collection of command style functions that make matplotlib work like MATLAB, matplotlib.figure.Figure is part of the object-oriented API.

In most cases you can configure figure settings via itself like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image=mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
my_fig = plt.imshow(image)
my_fig.axes.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
my_fig.axes.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
enter code here
```

**required stinkbug.png:**

[image: stinkbug.png]

**result:**

[image: screen.jpg]